# how java compare two primitive data type with different size

Tags: java, types, primitive, primitive-types

In Java how can two different primitive data types such as `int a = 3` and `byte b = 3` be compared?

I note the size of `int` is 4 bytes while `byte` is only 1 byte. Is it a bitwise comparison?

Comment: This is detailed in the Java specifications.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't. It never will.

```
int a = 3;
byte b = 3;
if (a == b) {
  ...
}
```

This is not a comparison between an `int` and a `byte`. `==` can only compare primitives of the same type. So this is a comparison between an `int` and an `int` (since `int` is the wider of the two). It is equivalent to the following more explicit code.

```
int a = 3;
byte b = 3;
if (a == (int)b) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a couple of exceptions, conceptually at least, the smaller type is converted to the larger type prior to the comparison being made.

The actual comparison will be typically performed by a machine code instruction directly on the CPU. These days the comparison will not be bit by bit; all the bits will be compared simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

If you perform any math or bitwise operation on primitive data types that are smaller than **int** (that is, byte, short, or char), those values will be promoted to **int** before performing the operation.

Consider the following code snippet and the generated byte code:

```
int  a = 1;
byte b = 1;

if (a == b) {
}

public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    ICONST_1
    ISTORE 1
   L1
    ICONST_1
    ISTORE 2
   L2
    ILOAD 1
    ILOAD 2
    IF_ICMPNE L3
   L3
    RETURN
```

As can be seen from the example above, both constants (a, b) are pushed onto the operand stack with the `ICONST` instruction as an `int` constants.

Answer (score 0):

Its performed through a [widening](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) process which does not lose information.

Comment: float and long is an important exception to this rule